# Combinatorics Problem From JMO

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways $four$ different numbers can be chosen from $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$                   such that the sum of those four numbers is divisible by $3$? Here $(a,b,c,d)$;$(b,a,c,d)$....are considered to be the same.

Comment: A bit frustrating to do, but I would recommend breaking into cases based on the number of each equivalence class of $\Bbb Z_3$ present in the selection.  You could have four elements from $[0]$,  two from $[0]$ and one from each of $[1]$ and $[2]$, one from $[0]$ and three from $[1]$, one from $[0]$ and three from $[2]$, or you could have two from each of $[1]$ and $[2]$.

Comment: You can also do it recursively.  Let $S(n,m,i)$ denote the number of ways to choose $m$ elements from $\{0,\cdots, n\}$ such that their sum is $\equiv i\pmod 3$.  Then the answer $S(9,4,0)= S(8,4,0)+S(8,3,0)$ and so on (in general, $S(n,m,i)=S(n-1,m,i)+S(n-1,m-1,i-m \pmod 3)$.

Comment: @JohnLou   An equal number?  Certainly not.  Never said there was.

Comment: @JohnLou  No problem.  To be clear, I'm not at all sure this is the best way to proceed if you need to do it by hand.  If I were automating it, I'd be inclined to go this way, however.

Comment: @JohnLou  Note:  there is a typo in what I wrote (maybe that error is the source of the confusion).  For the general recursion one has $S(n,m,i)=S(n-1,m,i)+S(n-1,m-1,i-n \pmod 3)$.

Comment: The reason you have downvotes on your question is likely because you have not shown your attempt. I can point you towards some terminology: " partitions in to *at most* 4 *distinct* parts with largest part size 9". Also see the generating functions: "[Gaussian Binomial Coefficients](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient)".

Comment: It might be useful to split into two cases, those numbers that include a 9 and those that do not, because if you exclude 9 then there are an equal number of representatives of each of the congruence classes mod 3, which may simplify analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, you can simplify the problem by taking $\bmod 3$.

The list $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ becomes $\{0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,0\}$.

Now lets list possible multiples of $3$.

$$1 1 1 0 : 4C1   = 1\cdot 4$$   (We have three ones and we need to select one $0$ from four $0$'s.)

$$1 1 2 2 : 3C2\cdot 3C2 = 9$$   (We have three $2$'s , three $1$'s and we need to select two $2$'s and $1$'s.)

$$1 2 0 0 : 3C1\cdot 3C1\cdot 4C2 = 54$$ (We have three $1$'s ,three $2$'s, four $0$'s and we need to select one $2$ and one $1$ and two $0$'s.)

$$2 2 2 0 : 3C3\cdot 4C1 = 4 .$$ (We need to select three $2$'s and one $0$).

$$0 0 0 0 : 1 .$$  (We need to select four $0$'s ).

Total : $4 + 9 + 54 + 4 + 1 = 72.$

Comment: (+1) Very good. I can verify this answer with a different method: Using Gaussian Binomial Coefficients it is the sum of the coefficients of terms $q^{3k}$ in ${10\brack 4}_q$ for $k=0\ldots 8$.